# Fancybox doesn't work with links like ?i=

Tags: jquery, fancybox

In my image gallery all link looks like this:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://my.domain/gallery/?i=001"></a>
```

Fancybox can't find the picture, and shows me the message: "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."
Please help with advice

Comment: what is the response of `my.domain/gallery/?i=001` looking with firebug? could post a demo page?

Comment: link my.domain/gallery/?i=001 response like that http://static.my.domain/images/cache/9/2/001--.jpg (by the way thickbox work fine with it)

Comment: My guess is that fancybox cannot guest the mime type of the resource since it does not have a filename extension.

Comment: @epignosisx : good guess. This is why you have to set what type of content it is (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `type` API option to your fancybox custom script and set it to `image` like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
 "type": "image"
});
```

Check http://fancybox.net/faq No. 6

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

```
<a href="http://my.domain/gallery/?i=001"></a>
```