# jquery fancybox fails to load image from Google High Performance Image Serving

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine, fancybox

Jquery fancybox 2 : The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later
When I try to load :

```
<div>
    <div>
        <a id="gae2" class="fancybox" href="https://lh3.ggpht.com/v22LQz8PX33f0Te34XmfyzOwgYHj_JDqVeD2nGzgvbzokD9MQ4qiUqT736a8xnErq6F6BHH8pEIM3VXW0zkUF-0GVp6l=s0">
            <img alt="gae1" src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/-KEglAPDnG3_y3hyFQCINGNg5ZxsRw5GRylPRrYFPTLmnNk0yQO4FGu1z1E92WljXhxH3SP3h8MBHkdbMvEenJ6RfcCwNw=s0">
        </a>
        <p><em>(Click to enlarge)</em></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above links have been generated using: images.get_serving_url (Python GAE) and work fine, but fancybox cannot handle them.

and my javascript:

```
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
```

Any ideas? Fancybox works fine when i try to load something like /images/test.jpg.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10658760/1055987

Comment: try removing the =s0 part of the URL

Comment: Thank you, Solved by adding "type", "image"